# How to use the title command JSON in 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently making a map in the Minecraft 1.13 snapshots and have encountered a problem. I want to use the `title` command to give the player the number of resources they have for a certain resource. For example Wood: 150. I looked this up and found you could do this using the `title` command. Example:

```
title @a[r=1] actionbar [{"text":"Wood: "},{"score":{"name":"@p","objective":"Wood"},"bold":true}]}}
```

This works in 1.12 but not in 1.13. It seems that the JSON format has changed in 1.13 but I can't find anything on the wiki or the changelog.

Could someone please help me to work this out?

Comment: This may just be because you're using the snapshots and not the full update (which obviously isn't out yet). I would suggest making it for 1.12, but that's your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many selector arguments have changed in 1.13. In this case, `r` is now a range called `distance`, so your selector should be: `@a[distance=..1]`

[Dinnerbone has a post](https://www.reddit.com/user/Dinnerbone/comments/6l6e3d/a_completely_incomplete_super_early_preview_of/) detailing most of the command-breaking changes in 1.13, which you may want to look through (a lot has changed, it is unlikely that a 1.12 command will work without any changes)

Your JSON has two stray `}`'s at the end making it invalid. The command should work after removing those:

```
/title @a[distance=..1] actionbar [{"text":"Wood: "},{"score":{"name":"@p","objective":"Wood"},"bold":true}]
```